# User deleted a set of lead assignment rules, and we cannot figure out how

Tags: leads, assignment-rules, lead-assignment

We have a few business users in our org who essentially have admin credentials. We have tried removing these permissions but ultimately our sales leadership said its not an option to remove their privileges.

One of these users accidentally deleted some lead assignment rules that impacted our org for a week before we found out. It caused a bit of chaos and issues. And now our leadership is looking for answers to exactly what happened.

This user doesn't know what lead assignment rules are, and really never goes into Setup other than to manage users. She claims she never went and deleted these rules and didn't know what they are, and generally she has never made any mistakes like this in the past.

Is there any other way to delete lead assignment rules other than directly going to lead assignment rules and deleting them? Is there anything she could have done while deactivating a user or something that could indirectly delete these rules?

I looked at the audit trail and there was nothing else she did at the time the assignment rules were deleted. She was deactivating users at a similar time, but didn't do anything else.

I tried googling it but i don't know of any ways of deleting assignment rules other than directly doing it. Does anyone know any other ways it can be deleted indirectly?

Thanks

Comment: Can't suggest any answer to the specific question, but would recommend you use this as a means to instigate a change in behaviour within your business - removing admin access and using the more restricted [delegated admin](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_delegate.htm&type=5) instead.